# Change url of ReviewSummary

Tags: theme, url, product-list

Deal with it,

In product list

```
app/design/frontend/ThemeName/blank/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

i've got

```
getRatingSummary()) echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
```

to see getReviewsSummaryHTML we need go deeper

```
app/design/frontend/ThemeName/blank/template/review/helper/summary_short.phtml
```

to see this

```
getRatingSummary()) echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
```

My question is: How can i change url of review stars on products list to product page url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the url of the product.
Check this http://makandracards.com/magento/8371-getting-a-products-url. Than replace `<a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>` with the desired url.

Inside summary_short.phtml, you should use: `$this->getProduct()->getProductUrl();`

Comment: You're Welcome.